# Link not working when clicked by Testcafe inside iframe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to sett upp some simple verification in our demoshop.
It works until clicking the  "genomför köp"  (make purchases) link is clicked.
The link markes as clicked (color change)  but the proper actions are not performedand you stay on the same side. 
if you add a debugline after the "await t.click('#purchase-button');" line you can click the link manualy, you can hover over the link so testcafe finds it.    But for some reason tha click()  dont work.

EDIT:1: the OS i am using is WIn10, running testcafe 1.8.2 under phpstorm 2019.3.3 and calling it with "testcafe chrome *.js"

Any help would be appreciated.
/Christoffer

Relevant code is below and the demoshop is open to use.

```
fixture`demoshop.resurs.com`
    .page(https://demoshop.resurs.com);


test(
    'Run: demoshop.resurs.com', async t => {
        await t
            .click('.home-shop-now')
            .click('#root > div > main > div > div.container > div.products-container.mb-60 > div:nth-child(1) > a > img')
            .click('#root > div > main > div > div > div.product-detail__container > div.product-detail__info-container > div.product-detail__add-to-cart > div > button')
            .click('#root > div > main > div > span > header > div > div > div > span.shopping-bag-icon.clickable > div')
            .click('#root > div > main > div > span > div > div > div > div.shopping-cart-container > a');

        await t.switchToIframe('iframe');

        await t.click('#purchase-button');  //This does not work properly

        await t.expect(Selector('h2').innerText).contains('Tack för din order!');


    }
);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the OS, browser, and TestCafe version you are using? I've checked your test with TestCafe v1.8.4 and found that switching to the main window is missing there. I added the `await t.switchToMainWindow();` action after the `#purchase-button` click, and the test was passed on my side.

Comment: Have uppdated the original post with the info you asked for.   and tried your change.  Unfortunately it did not work.    
Sorry about being late with my answer.  have spent the week in hospital after  geting an  acute appendicitis.  (not part of my plans :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue with TestCafe@1.8.2 but the test works as expected with TestCafe@1.8.4.

I recommend you update to the latest TestCafe version and apply changes provided by @DmitryOstashev:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture`demoshop.resurs.com`
    .page('https://demoshop.resurs.com');


test(
    'Run: demoshop.resurs.com', async t => {
        await t
            .click('.home-shop-now')
            .click('#root > div > main > div > div.container > div.products-container.mb-60 > div:nth-child(1) > a > img')
            .click('#root > div > main > div > div > div.product-detail__container > div.product-detail__info-container > div.product-detail__add-to-cart > div > button')
            .click('#root > div > main > div > span > header > div > div > div > span.shopping-bag-icon.clickable > div')
            .click('#root > div > main > div > span > div > div > div > div.shopping-cart-container > a');

        await t.switchToIframe('iframe');

        await t.click('#purchase-button');

        await t.switchToMainWindow();

        await t.expect(Selector('h2').innerText).contains('Tack för din order!');
    }
);
```

Comment: tnx.  works now.    Need to figure out why 1.8.2 could not handel that page.